# Identify covariance-like formula

Tags: probability, statistics

This might be a weird question, but in the process of some computation I obtained the following formula:

$$\text{E}[X^2]\text{E}[Y^2] - \text{E}[XY]^2$$

It kind of looks like a "quadratic" covariance, but I don't know what it actually means. Is there a mathematical meaning to this quantity?

Specifically, what kind of relationship between $X$ and $Y$ would ensure the above quantity is non-zero?

**UPDATE:** Seems this is equal to $\text{Var}(XY) - \text{Cov}(X^2, Y^2)$. Is there a clearer meaning to this anyway?